# The method someMethod(Class<Tokens.T>) is not applicable for Class<SomeClass>

Tags: java

I have a simple util method

```
  public static T getBeanByClass(Class<T> daoClass)
  {
    T bean = applicationContext.getBean(daoClass);
    return bean;
  }
```

Whenever I try to use it with

```
MyBeanClass bean = getBeanByClass(MyBeanClass.class);
```

the compiler complains saying

> The method getBeanByClass(`Class<Tokens.T>`) in the type Utils is not
>   applicable for the arguments (`Class<MyBeanClass>`)

Why is this? How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the wrong `T`, check your imports and use this:

```
public static <T> T getBeanByClass(Class<T> daoClass)
{
    T bean = applicationContext.getBean(daoClass);
    return bean;
}
```

Comment: definitely the right solution, maybe it's too early here to write some good code. Thanks a lot!